# Why is my APIservice called v1beta1.vpcresources.k8s.aws when it's actually apiregistration.k8s.io/v1 and not v1beta1?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to root out any old v1beta1 versions in my Kubernetes cluster but I'm getting strange results.
I have APIservice entries that are pre-pended by the word `v1beta1` and have `v1beta1` in the `spec.version` but the apiVersion is clearly `v1` see below...can anyone explain this?
[image]

....or
@user1984  you mean like this?

```
 [redacted]$ kubectl get ApIService -n <namespace-name>  
 v1beta1.vpcresources.k8s.aws -oyaml
apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: APIService
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "redacted"
  labels:
    kube-aggregator.kubernetes.io/automanaged: "true"
  name: v1beta1.vpcresources.k8s.aws
  resourceVersion: "redacted"
  uid: redacted
spec:
  group: vpcresources.k8s.aws
  groupPriorityMinimum: <value>
  version: v1beta1
  versionPriority: <value>
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "redacted"
    message: Local APIServices are always available
    reason: Local
    status: "True"
    type: Available
```

Comment: would be helpful to copy and format the command and output text.

Comment: @user1984  you mean like this?